# Script timed out before returning headers with Flask and AWS ELB

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, flask, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

This is a new error I started getting in my logs (which can be found [here](http://elasticbeanstalk-us-east-2-474813983089.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/resources/environments/logs/tail/e-wrqsxgan6i/i-081a7c39763462cbf/TailLogs-1534002270989.out?X-Amz-Algorithm=AWS4-HMAC-SHA256&X-Amz-Date=20180811T154432Z&X-Amz-SignedHeaders=host&X-Amz-Expires=86400&X-Amz-Credential=AKIAIKOSE77CLMRUGX3Q%2F20180811%2Fus-east-2%2Fs3%2Faws4_request&X-Amz-Signature=ae0238ff1e674631fb51cb27869486272aad50e5056e429a515bd8aa6f9e2357)). I followed some of the solutions from other stackoverflow posts but nothing worked.

My application.py file is very long so a link to it is [here](https://github.com/TheCreativeFoundation/accounts.tcff.co/blob/master/application.py).

Here is my .ebextensions/flask.config file:

```
option_settings:
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
        WSGIPath: application.py
    "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python:staticfiles":
        /static/: "static/"
```

Here is my .ebextensions/wsgi_custom.config file:

```
files:
    "/etc/httpd/conf.d/wsgi_custom.conf":
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
        WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
```

Comment: did you find any solution?!